# MCP4131 resistor on SDI/SDO multiplexed pin?

Tags: spi, multiplexer, digital-potentiometer

I'm using the [MCP4131 digital potentiometer](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en531882) to control the brightness of a LED using an Arduino Uno. The MCP4131's interface is SPI and it has a multiplexed SDI/SDO pin (pin #3).

The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22060b.pdf) specifies a resistor R1 to be placed on the host's SDO before the host SDI/SDO signal are being multiplexed. I was wondering how to calculate it's value? For now, I used a 1k resistor and it works but I want to learn how to deduce this value from the datasheet.

The comment says that R1 must be sized to ensure VIL and VIH of the devices are met, I can't figure out what these are.

If anyone can explain I'll appreciate it, thank!

[image]

Comment: You need to check comment 2, which says _"R1 must be sized to ensure VIL and VIH of the devices are met"_.  If you need help with this bit then perhaps adjust your question.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I modified the question as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still interested in a solution:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/248235/276980 provides an answer to this question.

Comment: In that case please flag to close this question as a duplicate of the other, as I've done so now.

Comment: In general please don't post answers that are nothing but a mere link to an external site. In case it's a link to a post on this site, you should instead flag the question and propose to close it as duplicate.