# multiple MCP4131 potentionmeters with common Slave Select line

Tags: spi, digital-potentiometer

I fiddle with a digital potentiometer MCP4131 which communicates via the SPI protocol. I've seen several tutorials in which multiple SPI devices are connected to a common Slave Select line and the bits of information overflow from the first Slave device to the second, etc.

I wonder weather would be possible to connect two MCP4131 potentiometers with a common Slave Select line, due to the fact that they have a common MISO/MOSI pin.

[image]

So, shouldn't MISO/MOSI be in different pins, thus connect MISO of the first device to the MOSI of the second one?

I am a bit confused, so any thought would be appreciated. The following articles didn't help me understand much.

[MCP4131: How to know what value resistors to use on the multiplexed SPI IO?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240852/mcp4131-how-to-know-what-value-resistors-to-use-on-the-multiplexed-spi-io)

[MCP4131 resistor on SDI/SDO multiplexed pin?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90838/mcp4131-resistor-on-sdi-sdo-multiplexed-pin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other digipots that DO have separate MOSI and MISO pins, this part cannot be simply daisy chained to save on IO pins.